# How to find a specific field from a genetic List object in wpf

Tags: wpf, list, generics

I am trying to create a generic class for finding duplicate values for different class.
I am casting each list to an object and passing it as parameter like this

```
List<StudentModel1> a = new List<StudentModel1>();
List<StudentModel2> b = new List<StudentModel2>();
List<StudentModel3> c = new List<StudentModel3>();

List<object> obj = a.Cast<object>().ToList();//like this

public bool Duplicate(List<object> obj, string Fieldname, string Name)
{
    if (obj.Any(x => x.Fieldname.Contains(Name))) { return true; } else { return false; }
}/// something like this;
```

here i am passing **fieldname propery** ,string name and object for finding duplicate and return a bool.How to access field name in linq.
please help how to acheive this.
thanks.

Comment: Just call `list.Any(x => x.SomeField.Contains("whatever")`. All your `Duplicate()` method is adding is a lot of problems trying to write it.

Comment: What is `Contains` doing in your above sample. Is the field you want to read always a string? Or some kind of collection?

Comment: I may have another solution for you if you can explain what you are trying to do with `Contains` per my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have 3 different versions of a class: `StudentModel1`, `StudentModel2` and `StudentModel3` and you want to be able to compare lists of them. You are casting them to `Object` so that you can pass any any version of that class to your `Duplicate` method.

Assuming the above is correct, what you need is [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance). If that's not something your familiar with you should definitely read up on it.

Consider the following:

```
    class StudentModelBase
    {
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }

    class StudentModel1 : StudentModelBase
    {

    }

    class StudentModel2 : StudentModelBase
    {

    }

    class StudentModel3 : StudentModelBase
    {

    }
```

If your `Duplicate` method should be able to handle any of the "StudentModel" classes, then that means the information needed to tell if there are duplicates must be common to all three versions of that class. The properties and fields which store that information should be moved into `StudentModelBase`. Then, instead of casting to `Object` you should cast to `StudentModelBase`.

Your cast becomes:

```
List<StudentModelBase> base = a.Cast<StudentModelBase>().ToList();
```

And your `Duplicate` method becomes something like the following:

```
public bool Duplicate(List<StudentModelBase> obj, string Name)
```

Notice I left out `Fieldname` because if this is implemented correctly you shouldn't need to pass that as a parameter. You should just be able to access the need members of `StudentModelBase` like any normal variable, since they should be the same for all versions of "StudentModel".

Comment: thanks for reply this wont work since class a,b,c have different property and base class has some property which shows casting error. not only i want to split each field from object using index or name for some other comparison